# Identification of a bug on lavatera

Tags: identification, bugs, parasites

[EDIT-20170626: added some history] I just found a couple of bugs on my [lavatera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lavatera), which seems to do fine so far. I has tried to find the bug species with the morphological description,  without success.

- Who could it be?
- Is it detrimental?

[image: lavatera bug]

[EDIT-20170626] This family album, after a few days wait, seems to suggest a southern green stink bug, at least in its intermediate lymph avatars.

[image: southern green stink bug]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option, looking at the different members of the family, seem to suggest a [southern green stink bug](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/veg/bean/southern_green_stink_bug.htm). Should it be handpicked remaining an open question.